# how to attach two classes on textarea field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i make a php form in which i want to validate the form but when i attach class=validate[required] on datetime and textarea field then other classes not apply on these,how i attach two classes on both?here is my code:

```
<textarea name="message" class="validate[required] ckeditor" id="message" cols="90" rows="15" style="width: 100%;"><?= $_POST['message'] ?></textarea>
```

class=chkeditor not attach when i attach class=validate[required],how i attach two class?

Comment: how are you adding the classes??

Comment: i edit my code see my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this..
leave a space b/w each class..

```
<textarea name="message" class="validate[required] ckeditor" id="message" cols="90" rows="15" style="width: 100%;"><?= $_POST['message'] ?></textarea>
```

Comment: i used your code but my chkeditor class applied but validate[required] class not applied

Comment: can u share a fiddle??

how are you adding the class??

Answer (score 0):

you can add any number of classes with space between each other.

Try like this:

```
<textarea name="message" class="validate[required] ckeditor" id="message" cols="90" rows="15" style="width: 100%;"><?= $_POST['message'] ?></textarea>
```

Comment: when i used your code my validate[required] class not applying on textarea

Comment: can you share what is in the `validate[required]` ?